# CSS width property for image

Tags: html, css

I want a 1200x300 resolution image on my webpage with width equal to the screen size and a height of 500px. My code doesn't seem to work. This is my CSS:

```css
 div.fix
 {   /*min-width:100%;*/
        /*width:100%;*/
        width:2000px;
  height:500px;
  position:fixed; 
  display:block;
  top: 0px;
  
    
 }
```

```html
<div class = "fix" ><img src="ARIA.png">
</div>   <!-- I have tried inline styling as well. But it doesnt work -->
```

I don't think this might be the reason, but is it because my image size is smaller than the specified size?

Thanks:)

Comment: May be it will help you. Please check this  link:-https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-responsive-images-with-srcset/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```css
.fix img{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "fix" >
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x300">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use background size cover property

div.fix
      {

```
    width:2000px;
    height:500px;
    position:fixed; 
    display:block;
    top: 0px;
    background-size:cover !important;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
 .fix img
 {   
        width:2000px;
  height:500px;
  position:fixed; 
  display:block;
  top: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div class = "fix" ><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
</div>   <!-- I have tried inline styling as well. But it doesnt work -->
```